# Validation to check a list of values from found on a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets in my workbook named `'Tasks'` and `'Personnel'`. The `'Personel'` sheet has three columns that contains a list of Person's ID, Name, and Contact Number.

[image]

While the `'Task'` sheet contains their tasks.

[image]

How can I give validation to `column C` of sheet `'Tasks'` for it to check its value from `column B2:B(n)` of sheet `'Personnel'`? I've tried providing a range as validation, but it's not accepted.

[image]

Comment: its works without equal (=) sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to close the question, I'll post my comment:

> its works without equal (=) sign